# Configure IntelliJ getter and setter code generation

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm use to defining member variables that are private with a prefix 'm'. Example:

```
private boolean mDone;
```

The getter / setter would typically look like this:

```
public boolean getDone() }
  return mDone;
}

public void setDone(boolean done) {
  mDone = done;
}
```

The Intellij IDE does have a way of creating these getters/setters but it adds the 'm' prefix to the names of the getter/setter methods. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my IntelliJ 15.0.3, I can navigate to:

```
File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Code Generation
```

and set "Name Prefix" as `m` in the `Naming` panel:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**solution:**

1. Go to `File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings`
2. In the search box, type `"prefix"`.
3. On the right, select the tab `"Code Generation"`.
4. In the `"prefix"` box, remove `m` (or whatever your prefix is)